# Can't run TCP client/server code on using cmd

Tags: java, tcp, cmd

I have this code but it doesn't run on cmd using windows. Doing this for the first time. When I try to run the server, there is no response (no error, but can't continue typing and nothing happens, and the same for the client1.

This is the code for the server:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class outputStream

{ 
    public static void main (String args [])throws Exception {

     // initialises Server Socket 
     ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket (1337);

    // waits for the connection of two clients C1 and C2 (in either order)
      while (true) {
        Socket socket1 = welcomeSocket.accept();
        Socket socket2 = welcomeSocket.accept();

        //gets input streams of the clients
        BufferedReader inFromclient1 = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(socket1.getInputStream()));  
        BufferedReader inFromclient2 = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(socket2.getInputStream()));
        //reads the data
        String client1Sentence = inFromclient1.readLine();
        String client2Sentence = inFromclient2.readLine();

        //get output streams of the clients 
        BufferedWriter outToclient1 = new BufferedWriter (new OutputStreamWriter (socket1.getOutputStream ()));
        BufferedWriter outToclient2 = new BufferedWriter (new OutputStreamWriter (socket2.getOutputStream ()));

        //replies to clients 
        String reply1 = " ";
        String reply2 = " ";

        if (client1Sentence.equals(client2Sentence)){
            reply1 = "xxxxx\n";
            reply2 = "yyyyy\n";
        } else if (client1Sentence.equals ('y') && client2Sentence.equals ('z')) {
           reply1 = "xxx\n";
           reply2 = "yyyyyy";
        }
         else if (client1Sentence.equals ('z') && client2Sentence.equals ('y')) {
           reply1 = "xxxx\n";
           reply2 = "yyyy\n";
        } 
        else if (client1Sentence.equals ('y') && client2Sentence.equals ('x')) {
           reply1 = "xxxxxxxx\n";
           reply2 = "yyyyy\n";
        } 
        else if (client1Sentence.equals ('P') && client2Sentence.equals ('R')) {
           reply1 = "xxxxxxx\n";
           reply2 = "yyyy\n";
        } 
         else if (client1Sentence.equals ('z') && client2Sentence.equals ('x')) {
           reply1 = "xxxx\n";
           reply2 = "yyyyyyy\n";
        } 
        else if (client1Sentence.equals ('x') && client2Sentence.equals ('z')) {
           reply1 = "xxxxx\n";
           reply2 = "yyyyyyy\n";
        } 


         //sends reply to clients 
        outToclient1.write(reply1,0,reply1.length());
        outToclient2.write(reply2,0, reply2.length());


        //ends connection
        outToclient1.flush();
        outToclient2.flush();  
     }
}
}

This is the code for Client1:

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class client1
{
    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class clientTCP
     */
    public static void main (String args[]) throws Exception {

        //intialises input/outputStream
        BufferedReader inFromUser = new
        BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in)); 

        //intialises client Socket
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket ("localhost",1337);

        //fetches input/outputSteam
        BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream())); 
        BufferedWriter outToServer = new BufferedWriter (new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream ()));


        //sends message to server and closes server connection
        String sentence = inFromUser.readLine();
        outToServer.write (sentence + "\n", 0, sentence.length()+1);
        outToServer.flush();

        //server reads line from client 
        String ack = inFromServer.readLine();

        //server replies to client
        System.out.println ("FROM SERVER:" + ack);

        // client socket is closed 
        clientSocket.close();   
    }
}
```

Comment: in the code you wrote your server will only work once two clients connect to it

Comment: Try to make it work with only one client first. As mentioned in one of the answers, the program will halt while waiting for the client to connect - "blocking" any further code below the blocking call. To begin with, try to add multiple System.out.println("Hello " + i) to understand where this is happening or create an extra debug function that prints to console when enabled by a flag set as field.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to create the extra debug function or how to solve the problem based on your answer. Can you break it down further, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`welcomeSocket.accept()` will block until a client connects, so unless you run two clients and one server, nothing will happen

Comment: I have opened the server and both clients in separate cmd windows, but still nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

The problem goes with the use of the `equals()`, the arguments should be enclosed in a double quotation and not a single quotation.